# Send Series of Batched API Requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, rxjs

Looking for a performant approach to send circa 1000+ requests in batches e.g 6 in parallel, and when these 6 have completed, send next 6

Sending in batches will prevent the browser request queue from fully blocking any other API requests that may occur while the batch calls are in progress

I have done this previously with `RxJS` (example below), but wondering is there an equivalent `fetch` `Promise` based approach?

```js
// Array of observables
const urls = [
  this.http.get('url1'),
  this.http.get('url2'),
  this.http.get('url3'),
  ...
];


bufferedRequests(urls) {
  from(urls).pipe(
    bufferCount(6),
    concatMap(buffer => forkJoin(buffer))
  ).subscribe(
    res => console.log(res),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('complete')
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [bottleneck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck) a while ago.

It allows you to bottleneck your requests with a client side rate limiter. You can choose how many requests to send out per minute and how many concurrent ones can run too.

You can set up a `limiter`:

```
const limiter = new Bottleneck({
 maxConcurrent: 1,
 minTime: 333 //this will execute 3 requests every second, aka wait 333 ms to execute the next request
});
```

then wrap your function with it.

```
const wrapped = limiter.wrap(myFunction);

wrapped(arg1, arg2)
.then((result) => {
  /* handle result */
});
```

In your case, I'd write a function that wraps around the fetch requests and returns a promise. Then, I would wrap that with the limiter. Here's an example:

```
const throttledGetMyData = limiter.wrap(yourFetchFunction);

  const allThePromises = requests.map(item => {
    return throttledGetMyData(request);
  })
  try {
    const results = await Promise.all(allThePromises);
    console.log(results);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do Promise.allSettled instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled